# Using SVN with PHP - Add command failing on already existing directories

Tags: php, svn

So basically I want to be able to do this:

```
        /*
            Runs command and checks return code of last command run. Throws SVN exception if non-zero status code is returned. The output of the command otherwise.
        */
        public static function runCommand($cmd)
        {
            //Redirect error to stdout
            $cmd .= " 2>&1";

            $output = array();
            exec($cmd, $output, $status);
            $output = implode("\n", $output);

            if($status != 0)
            {
                            //custom exception class - nonimportant
                throw new SvnException($output);
            }

            return $output;
        }
```

The issue is that `svn add` considers it an error when you try to add a directory that is already under version control so it returns an error status code. Is there anyway to fix this issue without putting in a hack to look for `svn add` commands and ignore the error if is the "directory already exists one"?

Specifically, is there some SVN commands I can use to tell if the folder is under version controlt, or arguments that I can use so that `svn add` does not return an error if the directory is already under version control.

Comment: I usually only loop through the files not yet tracked by `svn stat | egrep ^\\? | awk '{print $2;}'`

Comment: @Wrikken Unfortunately, I need a cross platform solution if at all possible. I will definitely try this out on Linux though.

Comment: Ah, yes, that line is by no means portable indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask svn if the directory exists. If you want your `add` function to mimic the `svn` one, just throw your Exception and have the caller deal with it. If you want it be silent when the directory already existsm add the check here.

Comment: Yeah, it just seems hacky to create an exception for a single use case but I guess there is no choice as I do not consider it an error but SVN does.

Comment: I ended up checking for an error with `svn info` and only add the directory if the command errored.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse SVN output for that particular error and add if() {} for that case.

I also highly recommend you to instead of exec() parsing use [SVN PHP extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/svn). It is easy to install, use and working perfectly (from my own experience)...

Comment: That project has not been worked on for over a year it looks like. Are you sure its completely stable? Also, I am only doing simple add/commits so a whole library would probably take longer to configure than just doing it myself in this case.

Comment: We are using all read only repository aspects of this extension (log, ls, diff,...) and it has worked perfectly for 3 years. I have not tried add and similar non-read-only methods but I have full confidence that they are valid. Also, if you rely on parsing output, the output could be changed with new SVN client version. This is faster, safer, better,... In one word - the right way (ok three words) :)